# How to find the unfollow page using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to find the unfollow page in Mysql and show a list of Pages that users dont follow, to make he follow...

This is my structure:

```
user: id, name [....]
page: id, name, up [...]
follows : id, user_id, page_id
```

I want to get a list of pages that user dont follow.

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?

Comment: Select distinct name, url_photos, up from page, follows where follows.category_id=page_id and follows.user_id!='$user_id'  @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select user.id as userid, page.id as pageid 
  from user, page 
  where pageid not in(select page_id from follows where user_id = userid)
```

http://ideone.com/ixAcxg

Comment: `#1054 - Unknown column 'pageid' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'`

Comment: `#1054 - Unknown column 'userid' in 'where clause'`

Comment: I am not getting these errors, check the ideone link.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select fol_usr.id,fol_usr.user_id,fol_usr.page_id,fol_usr.id,fol_usr.name,pg.id as pageid,pg.name as page_name,pg.up as page_up from
(select fol.id,fol.user_id,fol.page_id,usr.id,usr.name from
(select id,name from user) as u
(select id,user_id,page_id from follows)as fol
left JOIN
(SELECT id,name from user) as usr
on fol.user_id = usr.id) as fol_usr

left join

(select id, name,up from page) as pg
on fol_user.page_id = pg.id
```